# Programmatically expand/collapse Bottom Navigation View in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, bottomnavigationview

I have a `CoordinatorLayout` that contains a `BottomNavigationView` and an `AppBarLayout` with a `ToolBar` inside of it. (The `BottomNavigationView` is not inside the `AppBarLayout`, as doing it breaks the position of the `BottomNavigationView`).

I need to show/hide the `AppBarLayout` and the `BottomNavigationView` programmatically, when certain events happen (e.g. on a fragment's `onResume`), and so far I've managed setting `appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true)` in order to show/hide the AppBar, but I can't figure out how to do the same for the `BottomNavigationView`, as it does not have any method to show/hide itself.

The behaviour of my `BottomNavigationView` is `app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"`, set in the layout xml. How can I get a reference to this behaviour in my code in order to manage its expanded/collapsed state?

Answer (score 7):

Thats code slides up your bottom navigation that are inside of a Coordinator Layout and have a HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior.

If you are using findViewById just replace that for every `binding.`

```
val layoutParams = binding.bottomNavigation.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
val bottomViewNavigationBehavior = layoutParams.behavior as HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior
bottomViewNavigationBehavior.slideUp(binding.bottomNavigation)
```

Comment: is there any method to check its state? if it is hidden or not?

Answer (score -1):

You can hide `bottomNavigation` view from your fragment container activity. Because of you have `bottomNavigation` id. and you can access this id from your `fragment container activity` and also you can get the **current fragment instance** from your `fragment container activity`. So from your example if you want to hid bottom navigation from particular `fragment` `onResume()` event you can check that which fragment is currently visible from you Fragment container activity and call hide or show bottom navigation.

**Remember** for hiding or showing  bottom navigation use animation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a reference to my `BottomNavigationView`, the problem I'm facing is how to show/hide it, using the scroll animation defined bu the behaviour programatically. Thus, I need to get a reference to the behaviour and call "show" or "hide" on it.

Comment: Why you need reference of the behavior? You have scroll change listener right ?

Comment: Yes, I can add one, but is this the way to go? On the `AppBarLayout ` there is a `setExpanded` method, which is how you're supposed to do this. Is there a way to do something similar for the `BottomNavigaitonView`?

Comment: I think no. you have to use setVisiblility().

Comment: But then, when the user scrolls "up", the BottomNavigaitonView will not appear, defeating the point of the CoordinatorLayout and the Behaviour, If I implement my own onScrollListener

Comment: Question is when you wan to show or hide bottom navigation view? If you want show/hide while scrolling it has own behavior with co-ordinator layout and it handle itsself. If you want to hide specific case like if fragment A is appear then you can use visibility