# Programmatically expand/collapse Bottom Navigation View in CoordinatorLayout [Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin, android-coordinatorlayout, bottomnavigationview

Prior to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58412056/7795072), `setVisibility` works but the problem is,

> `visibility = true`, after hiding(using `visibility = gone`) the `BottomNavigationView`, shows up a blank space

the blank space is the space of the `BNV`, but no layout is inflated in it, due to the `HideViewOnScrollBehavior`

**Q:** How to expand the `BNV` programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Try setting visibility to GONE

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#GONE

Comment: that is what i use in hiding it, but i don't want to hide/show, i want to expand like the scroll behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Here with `Transition` effect, first place this `fade_in_out.xml` file in your `transition` resource folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:transitionOrdering="sequential">
    <fade android:fadingMode="fade_out" />
    <changeBounds />
    <fade android:fadingMode="fade_in" />
</transitionSet>
```

Then create two global variable in your `Activity` or `Fragment` as follows:

```
private var expanded = false
private lateinit var toggle: Transition
```

Then initialize the `toggle` variable in your `onCreate()` like:

```
toggle = TransitionInflater.from(requireContext()).inflateTransition(R.transition.fade_in_out)
```

Then use this `toggleExpanded()` function to expand or collapse your collapsible view.

```
fun toggleExpanded() {
    expanded = !expanded
    toggle.duration = if (expanded) 200L else 150L
    // Here rootView is the root layout of your layout resource file
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(binding.rootView as ViewGroup, toggle)
    // 'expandableView' is the view that expands and collapse
    binding.expandableView.visibility = if (expanded) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```